# JQuery Ajax call returns "Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am getting the above error when I am trying to pass the result.target of an OnLoad event in the FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer call using an jQuery Ajax POST call. The POST call is not actually being made (as monitored by Fiddler). This call works for files tested to about 120 mbs. I am trying to upload a 218 mb file though now. Also this seems to be IE specific, as it works in Chrome.

Call:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: url,
 contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
 data: fileData,
 processData: false,
 headers: { ACCEPT: 'application/json;odata=verbose', "X-RequestDigest": formDigest, "If-Match": "*" }
}).done(function (results) {
    //Do Stuff
});
```

As context, fileData is the result.target created through a file upload via the HTML 5 File API. I am trying to pass a file to upload in SharePoint via the Web API.

Comment: I'm also seeing this,  it seems to happen only to IE11 (not Edge not, Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Servers usually have limits on file sizes that can be uploaded. It sounds like you're running into the servers limit. If you own the server, you can raise the cap, otherwise you could try asking the server's admin.

Comment: Correct servers do have limits, but In the OP he states "that the POST call is not being made" This is a client issue.